# python/pandas/one dimensional dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Creating a 2 dimensional dataframe works fine:

```
y = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
df = pd.DataFrame( y, index=[1,2], columns=["a","b"] )
print (df)
```

But if I try to create a one dimensional dataframe I get an error message:

```
z = np.array([5,6])
df2 = pd.DataFrame( z, index=[3], columns=["a","b"])
print (df2)

Error message: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (2, 1)
```

I tried:

```
z = np.array([[5],[6]])
```

But I get the same error message.

The reason I might want to create a one dimensional dataframe is so I can append a single row to an existing dataframe. It wont let me append a list or an array so I have to turn it into a dataframe first. But I cant do that either

I am using anaconda

Answer (score 5):

Just adding `[]`

```
z = np.array([5,6])
df2 = pd.DataFrame( [z], index=[3], columns=["a","b"])
df2
Out[67]: 
   a  b
3  5  6
```

Comment: Short and sweet. I love it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a dataframe from a 1D array. Add another dimension to the array before passing it to the constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(z[np.newaxis,:], index=[3], columns=["a","b"])
#   a  b
#3  5  6
```

Comment: That weird. I can create a 2 dimensional dataframe with 2 rows and then delete one of the rows but I cant create a dataframe with only one row. Seems like an oversight on the part of the programmers to me

Comment: You confuse 1D vectors and 2D tables that have only one row. They are different objects. Removing a row from a two-row dataframe does not make it a 1D dataframe.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thank you. You have helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution would be switching index and column and applying transpose.

```
z = np.array([5,6])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(z, columns=[3], index=["a","b"]).T
df2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**BENCHMARK!!!**

TLDR: use `np.atleast_2d()`

```py
z = np.array([5,6])
%timeit pd.DataFrame([z], index=[3], columns=["a","b"])
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.atleast_2d(z), index=[3], columns=["a","b"])
%timeit pd.DataFrame(z[np.newaxis,:], index=[3], columns=["a","b"])

# 1.17 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# 754 µs ± 49.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# 878 µs ± 183 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```