# Change dimension of Dask dataframe/array?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am setting up a machine learning pipeline in dask through SKlearn. The fit function for the classifier requires the explanatory and target variables ( X and Y train).

Currently running a local cluster via the dask client.

```
X=df.iloc[:,[0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]]
Y=df.iloc[:,[12]]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,random_state=0) #testsize=0.1
estimator2 = RFClassifier(n_jobs=-1,random_state=10)
clf2 = Incremental(estimator1)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-3ee1fd4128bb> in <module>()
----> 1 clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\wrappers.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_kwargs)
    483     def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_kwargs):
    484         estimator = sklearn.base.clone(self.estimator)
--> 485         self._fit_for_estimator(estimator, X, y, **fit_kwargs)
    486         return self
    487 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\wrappers.py in _fit_for_estimator(self, estimator, X, y, **fit_kwargs)
    474                 random_state=self.random_state,
    475                 shuffle_blocks=self.shuffle_blocks,
--> 476                 **fit_kwargs
    477             )
    478 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\_partial.py in fit(model, x, y, compute, shuffle_blocks, random_state, **kwargs)
    169             y = y.to_dask_array()
    170 
--> 171         assert y.ndim == 1
    172         assert x.chunks[0] == y.chunks[0]
```

As can be seen from the error raised, the function expected a dimensionality of 1, however the dask dataframe for the y variable is of ndim 2. I am not sure why as can be seen from the chunk below, there is only 1 column.

```
y_train.columns.values
>>> array(['label'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I suspect that the function transforms the dataset into an array, whereby each element here is for some reason a list of length 1. Thus, creating a multidimensional array. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Essentially the opposite of whats being done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340276/python-pandas-one-dimensional-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that if you pass a series rather than a dataframe that things will work well

So do this

```
# Y=df.iloc[:,[12]]
Y=df.iloc[:,12]
```

Or this

```
# clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train.label)
```